# Nested html from json ( tree) JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have json like this

```
{
   desc: "text",
   nodes: [{
       desc: "text1",
       nodes: [
           {desc: "text3"},
           {desc: "text4"}
       ]},
       {desc: "text2",
       nodes: [
          {desc: "text5"} 
       ]}
   ]
}
```

And my problem is to create nested html object like:

```
<div> 
   text
   <div> text1 
         <div> text3 </div>
         <div> text4 </div>
   </div>

   <div> text2 
         <div> text5 </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was trying

```
function buildTree(tree) {  
    let node = tree;
    var el = document.createElement('div');

    if (Array.isArray(node.nodes)) {
        buildTree(node.nodes, el);
    } 
    else if (typeof(node.nodes) == 'object') {
        buildTree([node.nodes], el);
    }
    else {
      el.innerHTML = node.desc;
    }

}
buildTree(json_obj);
```

It can be plain text, (it is easy to parse) but i cant handle with this problem, i was trying recursion but it all break :/

Best regards

Comment: show us what you already tried

Comment: What you need is What you need is recursion recursion. It would help a lot to see what you tried already so we can help diagnose the errors

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that you are not appending the generated `el` to the DOM, so it is all created but never appended. Use `.appendChild(node)` to achieve what you want:

```
function buildTree(tree) {
  let node = tree;
  var el = document.createElement('div');

  el.innerHTML = node.desc;

  if (node.nodes) {
    node.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
      el.appendChild(buildTree(n));
    });
  }

  return el;
}
var tree = buildTree(data);
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(tree);
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var data = {
  desc: "text",
  nodes: [{
      desc: "text1",
      nodes: [{
          desc: "text3"
        },
        {
          desc: "text4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      desc: "text2",
      nodes: [{
        desc: "text5"
      }]
    }
  ]
};

function buildTree(tree) {
  let node = tree;
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  
  el.innerHTML = node.desc;
  
  if (node.nodes) {
    node.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
      el.appendChild(buildTree(n));
    });
  }

  return el;
}
var tree = buildTree(data);
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(tree);
```

```css
div {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```